# No need to pay tax on long term capital gains under 40K?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax

In the long term capital gains tax brackets, I saw that the tax rate is zero percent for Singles up to 40K.
So if I am single, and have capital gains under 40K, then I don't need to pay any taxes on that long term capital gains?

Comment: Do you have any other earned income (like from a job)?

Comment: Yes, my salaried annual income is greater than 40K.

Comment: Neardupe https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/123816/0-in-taxes-if-capital-gains-and-ordinary-income-meet-this-threshold

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So if I am single, and have capital gains under 40K, then I don't need to pay any taxes on that long term capital gains?

Only if that's your *only taxable income*. The brackets are based on your taxable income, not your long-term gains, so if you have other taxable income (including short-term gains) of $40k, and have $40k of LTCG, then your LTCG will be taxed at 15% (the single filer rate for income between $40K and $440k as of 2021), not 0%.

Comment: So, I have to pay taxes on LTCG even though they are below 40K, when I have other income. Thanks